# Multiple feature files execution(include and exclude of tags) using command line arguments in selenium cucumber script

Tags: selenium, cucumber

I am able to execute selenium cucumber tests using command line like

`mvn clean test -DCucumber.options"--tags=@Addversion,~@Import"`

am excluding @Import tag. But it is executing both the features.

I implemented my test class like this

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@Cucumber.Options(features = "src/test/resources/featureFiles",//path to the features
format ={"json:target/integration_cucumber.json"}//what formatters to use
)
public class RunCucumberTest {
}
```

`src/test/resources/featureFiles` is my feature file location.

In this location I added two feature files using `@Addversion` and `@Import`

If I include tags option in my test class I am able to exclude(like `~@Import`) particular feature file using eclipse.

But am not able to exclude particular feature file using command line.

Can any one give me any suggestions about this.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem to run feature file by excluding some of the tags

I changed my test class

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
public class RunCucumberTest {
}
```

And in command line argument  specified feature files as option-less arguments like

```
mvn install -Dcucumber.options="src/test/resources/featureFiles --tags @Addversion,@~Import"
```